# Cloning ERC20/ERC721

Tags: solidity, erc-20, factory, design-patterns, clone

I'm using a `Clone Factory` pattern to create new instances cheaper. I realized that every field, preset or set in constructor, has default value. Let's assume that I have this contract:

```
contract MyToken is ERC20, Ownable {
    uint256 public presetValue = 1;
    uint256 public constructorValue;

    constructor() ERC20("MyToken", "MTKN") {
        constructorValue = 2;
    }
}
```

This contract is my, let's call it "Master contract" or "Base contract". Then I have a contract with `createClone` function:

```
  function createClone(address target) internal returns (address result) {
    bytes20 targetBytes = bytes20(target);
    assembly {
      let clone := mload(0x40)
      mstore(clone, 0x3d602d80600a3d3981f3363d3d373d3d3d363d73000000000000000000000000)
      mstore(add(clone, 0x14), targetBytes)
      mstore(add(clone, 0x28), 0x5af43d82803e903d91602b57fd5bf30000000000000000000000000000000000)
      result := create(0, clone, 0x37)
    }
  }
```

New instance of `MyToken` will have `name()` equal to empty string and `symbol()` equal to empty string as well (ERC20 fields). Now this is a problem which must be solved. Since OpenZeppelin's ERC20/721 have private fields I assume I need to implement my own ERC20/721 token with, for example `setName()` and `setSymbol()` functions and then some kind of aggregate called `initialize()` which will call those two functions and set those and other values? Also `presetValue` and `constructorValue` which obviously will be empty in cloned contract? Or there is another way?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you got it down.  A big downside to clones, but the "clone then init" is standard.  Many a projects have failed to init and left holes in their system, so one best practice is to write safeguards that require init to be run before things can operate.